# PHP - Checkbox saving value to Database

Tags: php, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a few `checkbox` in a form and I'm setting each value if its `checked` or `unchecked`.
So a checkbox that is `checked` has a value of `TRUE` and unchecked as `FALSE`
If I have all of the checkbox checked(value is `TRUE`) and I unchecked one of them, the other checkbox also unchecked and the value on the database also become `FALSE`. I can't understand the behavior below is my code

HTML

```
                    <label><input type="checkbox" id="trans_val_identical" value="FALSE">II Transaction Value of Identical Goods</label>

                   <label><input type="checkbox" id="trans_val_identical" checked="checked" value="FALSE">II Transaction Value of Identical Goods</label>


              </div>
              <div class="checkbox">

                     <label><input type="checkbox" id="trans_val_similar" value="FALSE">III Transaction Value of Similar Goods</label>

                     <label><input type="checkbox" id="trans_val_similar" checked="checked" value="FALSE">III Transaction Value of Similar Goods</label>

              </div>
              <div class="checkbox">

                     <label><input type="checkbox" id="deductive_val" value="FALSE">IV Deductive Value</label>

                     <label><input type="checkbox" id="deductive_val" checked="checked" value="FALSE">IV Deductive Value</label>

              </div>
              <div class="checkbox">

                     <label><input type="checkbox" id="computed_val" value="FALSE">V Computed Value</label>


                     <label><input type="checkbox"  id="computed_val" checked="checked" value="FALSE">V Computed Value</label>

              </div>
              <div class="checkbox">

                     <label><input type="checkbox" id="fallback_val" value="FALSE">VI Fallback Value</label>

                     <label><input type="checkbox" id="fallback_val" checked="checked" value="FALSE">VI Fallback Value</label>
```

JS

```
    $('#trans_val_identical').change(function(){
     if($(this).attr('checked')){
          $(this).val('TRUE');
     }else{
          $(this).val('FALSE');
     }
});
$('#trans_val_similar').change(function(){
     if($(this).attr('checked')){
          $(this).val('TRUE');
     }else{
          $(this).val('FALSE');
     }
});
$('#deductive_val').change(function(){
     if($(this).attr('checked')){
          $(this).val('TRUE');
     }else{
          $(this).val('FALSE');
     }
});
$('#computed_val').change(function(){
     if($(this).attr('checked')){
          $(this).val('TRUE');
     }else{
          $(this).val('FALSE');
     }
});
$('#fallback_val').change(function(){
     if($(this).attr('checked')){
          $(this).val('TRUE');
     }else{
          $(this).val('FALSE');
     }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues here:

The first is that your checkbox elements don't have names, which means they aren't going to be passed properly to the server with their values.  Make sure they have names so that you can refer to them in your PHP script and save them properly to the database.

Second, your understanding of how checkboxes are submitted in a form is a bit off.  The `value` attribute of a checkbox is submitted if it's checked, and it's not submitted if it's unchecked.  So you shouldn't change the value from TRUE to FALSE or vice-versa.

So if you have something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="trans_val_identical" value="1">
```

Then `$_POST['trans_val_identical']` (assuming you're using post to submit the form) will be "1" if the checkbox is checked, and it will be non-existent if the checkbox is unchecked.  So to check if the checkbox is checked in PHP, you'd use something like this:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['trans_val_identical'] )) {
    // The checkbox is checked
} else {
    // The checkbox is not checked
}
```